# Замена разделителя в input(type = date). HTML5

Tags: html

Подскажите как можно на чистом HTML изменить разделитель в теге `input`, типа `date`.

У меня есть вот такой код:

```html
<label>Введите дату: <input name="userDate" type="date"></label>
```

где между вводимым днем, месяцем и годом стоит '.' в качестве разделителя. Если я хочу поменять его на '-', к примеру, то как это сделать?

Пробовал вот так:

```html
<label>Введите дату: <input name="userDate" type="date" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"></label>
```

Но результат тот же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На чистом HTML5 этого сделать нельзя. Альтернатива, используя только HTML5:

```html
<label>Введите дату: <input type="text" placeholder="дд-мм-гггг" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')"></label>
```

P.s. есть косяк с тем, что после нажатия опять появляется формат с '.' в качестве разделителя, но это уже исправить, используя только разметку, видимо, нельзя.